# CSS code for 1 content bar and 2 sidebars

Tags: html, css

I have created a 'noob' page and I want to stylize it using CSS, and up to some extent I have done something.

I want my content to appear in center while with (white background) and two sidebars (left and right) `color:blue`;

For this page: http://blogsoc.org/mail
I am editing the code here: blogsoc.org/mail1

Like this (Screenshot): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46445635/stack%20question%20copy.png

Comment: [Try this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm).

Comment: @JezenThomas site was informative but not helpful to me. I thought it would generate code. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place all your content into `#container` block.

```
body { background-color: blue; }
#container { margin: 0 auto; width: 989px; background: white; }
```

`margin: 0 auto` makes your block centered vertically.

`width: 989px` is the safe area for 1024x768 screens.

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { background-color: blue; }
            #container { margin: 0 auto; width: 989px; background: white; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!-- All your current content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand how your answer helps him at all.

Comment: Thanks. That means I have to creat container divs first :/ Just discovered.

Comment: @JezenThomas I don't see any sidebar in the example, just some content, which should lie inside white block, while outside background should be blue.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil You're Welcome. Actually, you can just set body `background-image` to something with 989px in width and with `repeat: repeat-y` option. :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits Hmm. I have set background-color:#F0F0F0 But how to do 989px thingy? :/

Comment: Thanks. That code did the trick (somehow) but still the which box is shown in center (I mean the blue background is shown in up-side and downside. check: http://blogsoc.org/mail1

Comment: Then you can set property `height: 100%` to your `html`, `body` and `#container` elements, and add `margin:0;adding:0;` to `html` and `body`

Answer (score 1):

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/R8S6h/2/show/

*(remove the `show/` to see the code)*

Comment: Thanks. That;s a nice tool. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try that (http://jsfiddle.net/wh8RS/ and http://jsfiddle.net/wh8RS/show/):

CSS:

```
html,body{
 overflow:auto;
}
body{
 margin:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
.clear{clear:both;}
#wrapper{
 overflow:hidden;
 min-height:100%;
}
#sidebarleft,#sidebarright{
 background-color:blue;
 width:250px;
 max-width:25%;
 margin-bottom: -10000px;
 padding-bottom: 10000px;
 min-height:100%;
}
#sidebarleft{
 float:left;
}
#sidebarright{
 float:right;
}
#main{overflow:hidden}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="sidebarleft">Text 1</div>
<div id="sidebarright">Text 2</div>
<div id="main">Text 3</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
```